# Shrub Identification, Edible or not?

Tags: identification, wildflowers, edible

While looking for wild edibles I came across this shrub with some berries on it, fortunately some plants still had flowers so I was able to take many pictures. If anybody knows about it I would be glad to know if it is edible or not because the forest near my house is filled with these plants and the are all starting to fruit.

[image: The leave of the plant]

[image: Flowers with berries]

[image: Overall plant]

[image: Overall plant 2]

[image: Berries of the plant]

Comment: Its Fuchsia boliviana,  will post answer

Comment: I certainly hope you aren't tasting plants yet.  You have to have an expert with you, not just a book.  Otherwise, do not taste wild plants.  Especially where mushrooms are concerned.  Think apical tips, look that up for 'edibles' in the wilderness.  Those will make up the bulk of food in the forest.  Know your plants.  If you do not know for sure what that plant is do not eat it.  Never go foraging for food on an empty stomach.  Never go to the grocery store on an empty stomach?  Same thing.  Low blood sugar  can make decision making and driving cars deadly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This plant is, as Jurp says, a Fuchsia, but its actually Fuchsia boliviana. The fruits are edible, but as already said, are not usually very tasty so may be made into a jam or jelly, though they can be eaten raw if you want http://www.strangewonderfulthings.com/125.htm

Answer (score 3):

The plant is a fuchsia, possibly Fuchsia magellanica: http://www.perennials.com/plants/fuchsia-magellanica.html or Fuchsia triphylla: https://plantsam.com/fuchsia-triphylla/. Looks more like triphylla to me...

Although considered to be edible, fuchsia fruit is not very tasty. it can apparently be made into a nice jelly, however, which kind of puts them in the same league as black currant. Here's some info: http://www.americanfuchsiasociety.org/articledirectory/are-fuchsias-poisonous/.

Comment: I don't think its either of those - F magellanica has an inner part to the flower which is usually a different colour, comprised of 4 petals in a tube shape. The leaves appear to be way to large to be either of these varieties, though the seed pods do strongly resemble fuchsia